# how to subset the nth rows in ssis data flow?

Tags: ssis

I get a set of data from flat file, it looks like this:
[image]

However, I actually only want the 6-13 rows in column 1, is there anyway I can subset the column 1 by row number?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes/No. You can skip the first N rows which allows you start on row 6. However, there's functionality to terminate a flat file reader until it's consume the entire file.

Comment: @VerseHe are this Flat File a excel saved into a csv file?

Comment: @ Yahfoufi, yes, for some reason it won't be read by excel source so I try to use flat file source.

Comment: @billinkc, could you please show more details about this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you really want to filter rows by its position, it requires minor programming.

- First, create a script transformation in your data flow to generate row number. Here is a [good example](https://hansmichielscom.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/how-to-add-a-rownumber-to-a-data-flow-task-in-ssis-2012/) of such script. Assume row number will be stored in column RN.
- Add **Split rows** transformation with criteria `[RN]>=6 && [RN]<=13`. Name its output as **Filtered rows**.

Output **Filtered Rows** will contain only rows with row number between 6 and 13. Similarly you can filter out other row intervals.

Comment: @ Ferdipux  Thanks a lot, your solution perfectly solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Execute SQL task and load the data in the flat file source to a Temporary staging table and then query that temp table by using a WHERE clause with BETWEEN condition in it.